# Google Pie Chart not showing in broser

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, google-visualization

I'm trying to populate a data table from a List object and then display the result in a pie chart. For some reason which I cannot identify the pie chart is not showing in the browser (blank page). Below is my code. Can someone try to run this code and identify were is the error!... since I cannot identify were I'm wrong.

The Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(dataValues) {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.AddColumn('string', 'Locality');
            data.AddColumn('number', 'Frequency');

            for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                data.AddRow(dataValues[i].aString, dataValues[i].anInt);
            }

            var options = { 'title': 'Pie Chart Test',
                'width': 900,
                'height': 500
            };

               var chart =  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
               chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<Items> dataList = new List<Items>();
            dataList.Add(new Items("A", 10));
            dataList.Add(new Items("B", 20));
            dataList.Add(new Items("C", 30));

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Test", string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">drawVisualization({0});</script>", jss.Serialize(dataList)));
        }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string aString = "";
        public int anInt = 0;

        public Items(string _aString, int _anInt)
        {
        aString = _aString;
        anInt = _anInt;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: You shouldn't change your question to reflect corrections from answers.  It can confuse future visitors.  They might think, "Why does this answer say that the method names are wrong? It looks right to me!".  If an answer to your question only gives you part of what you need, leave a comment, or ask a whole new question, focusing only on the remaining issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.  The method names are [`.addColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn) and [`.addRow()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#addrow), but you are using `.AddColumn()` and `.AddRow()`.  Check your JavaScript console for errors.  You should find a message saying something like `undefined is not a function`.

The `.addRow()` method takes an array as its argument, but you are passing in two scalar values.  Wrap those up in square brackets: `data.addRow([dataValues[i].aString, dataValues[i].anInt])`.

You may also run into issues with your use of `RegisterStartupScript()`.  Your startup script may run before the visualization package has finished loading.  Instead, I would embed the value in a hidden field on the page and read that value from your script.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ChartData" />
```

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<Items> dataList = new List<Items>();
        dataList.Add(new Items("A", 10));
        dataList.Add(new Items("B", 20));
        dataList.Add(new Items("C", 30));

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        this.ChartData.Value = jss.Serialize(dataList);
    }
}
```

```js
function drawChart() {
    var dataValues = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("<%= ChartData.ClientID %>").value);
    // The rest of the function as written
}
```

Snippet with all the changes applied:

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var dataValues = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("ChartData").value);
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Locality');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');

    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
        data.addRow([dataValues[i].aString, dataValues[i].anInt]);
    }

    var options = { 'title': 'Pie Chart Test',
        'width': 900,
        'height': 500
    };

    var chart =  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="ChartData" value="[{&quot;aString&quot;:&quot;A&quot;,&quot;anInt&quot;:10},{&quot;aString&quot;:&quot;B&quot;,&quot;anInt&quot;:20},{&quot;aString&quot;:&quot;C&quot;,&quot;anInt&quot;:30}]" />
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Gilly. I corrected the method names but now I'm getting only the title and a No Data found.

Comment: @user2307236 - I thought that might happen. I've updated my answer to address what is most likely happening.

Comment: I made an additional edit, simulating the server component, and, after fixing an issue with the way you were calling `.addRow()`, my snippet is now displaying a pie chart.

Comment: Do I just need to copy "<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ChartData" />" and paste this line into the the body or am I missing something because it is giving me an error.

Comment: I managed Gilly to draw the chart. This was the first step for drawing charts dynamically on button click for client side. Tks a lot.